# If a definite integral is zero, i.e. $\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx=0$, then how can I prove that there exist $b$ such that $a < b < c$ and $f(b) = 0$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This result is so obvious intuitively, when the function is partly positive and partly negative, but I cannot find a mathematical way to prove it.
Assuming that the function is continuous.

Comment: You should, no you must require your function to be continuous, for this to be true.

Comment: you forgot 2 assumptions: $a\neq c$ and $f$ must be continous. in that case, assume $f(b)\neq 0$ for all $b$. Thus either $f>0$ or $f<0$ and $\int_{[a,c]}f>0$ or $\int_{[a,c]}f<0$.

Comment: Okay, I forgot about that. I have edited it now. But even then how to prove the result?

Comment: i already gave you a proof!

Comment: @kolobokish not true. you do not necessairily need that assumption: take any function and modify it to be zeron on $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand your proof. Also I do however understand that at some point the function has to cross zero, because the positive area will cancel out the negative area. But I want a mathematical proof that the function crosses zero at one point. Thanks.

Comment: it is an indirect proof. ($A\rightarrow B\Leftrightarrow \neg B\rightarrow\neg A$)

Comment: @Max Oh Max, what you say, just takes $f$ to be 0 at some point. Which was in the question.

Comment: @kolobokish you are saying the assumption of continuity is necessary, whereas it is just sufficient.

Comment: @kolobokish take any discontinous function $f$ and 2 reals $a,c$ such that $\int_{[a,c]} f=0$. now modify $f$ such that it is zero on $\mathbb{Q}$. Clearly $\int_{[a,c]}=0$ and $f$ has infinitely many zeros. so the *must* you wrote is wrong. the assertion also holds for some discontinous functions. It would also be enough to assume $f$ to have no jumps crossing zero. EDIT: shame on me, i also wrote "must" in my first comment.

Comment: I understand what you all saying, i.e., If the function changes sign it must cross zero at some point which is fine and the way I thought about the proof. But is there a step by step mathematical proof?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. Take 
$
f(x)=-1
$
on the first half of the interval and $1$ on the second half.

It is however true for continuous functions.

edit: Given the discussion above, I think what is bugging you is where the continuity assumption comes into play.

First assume $f\ne 0$ on the interval for the sake of contradiction. Then I claim with the continuity assumption, we can take $f<0$ or $f>0$ on the interval. This follows directly from the intermediate value theorem. If your function changes signs, it has a root.

Then $f(x)>0$ for any $x\in [a,c]$ without any loss of generality. Then we use the monotonicity of the integral to find
$$
\int_a^cf(t)dt>0
$$
a contradiction of the assumption $\int_a^cf(t)dt=0$.

Comment: When the function is continuous how to prove the result?

Comment: What @max said in the above is fine

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your function is continious. 
Then let $\int f(x) $ - area of then consider $f(\frac{a+c}{2})$. If it's zero then we find it. If it's more then zero then we should go left , less then zero - right. Suppose we have infinite sequence of $|[a_{i},c_{i}]| \to0$ , so there is point $b $ in intersaction of all segments. And because of continuity : $\lim_{i \to \infty}f(a_{i}) \le 0 $, $\lim_{i \to \infty}f(c_{i}) \ge 0 $, so there is $f(b) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$
F(t)=\int_{a}^{t} f(x)\,dx
$$
Then $F(a)=0$ and $F(c)=0$. Apply Rolle's theorem and the fundamental theorem of calculus.